Как исключить GET и прочие параметры из URL? (Nginx)
location ~* ^/(sitemap.xml|robots.txt)$ {
    rewrite ^ /seo.php;
}

Работает, в PHP:
switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']){
    case '/sitemap.xml':

Трудность в том, что какие бы GET параметры не подставить в URL, будет срабатывать правило – подгружать скрипт. Не 404 ошибку выдавать...
Как выполнить так, чтобы на случай дополнительных GET параметров, отдавало 404 код? Как регулярку написать?
Второй вопрос, хотелось бы так же разобраться, как внутри блока, определить, что есть GET параметры. И выполнить перенаправление без них...

По-моему вы усложняете себе жизнь, пытаясь запихнуть всё на свете в конфиг nginx, «нормальные» сайты обычно делают всю свою маршрутизацию в своём php-скрипте
